# Sorting in lexicographical order

Tags: ruby, sorting

So I want to sort my array of coordinates in lexicographical order. But I'm not sure how to do that. Each element in the array is a `Coordinate` object, with `Fixnum` fields `#x` and `#y`.

I'm new to Ruby and don't necessarily understand the sort enumeration. 
Would it be something like this?

```
coordinate_array.sort! { |a,b| a.x <==> b.x && a.y <==> b.y }
```

Comment: You can improve your question by adding a short input and the result of computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the spaceship operator is `<=>` not `<==>`

Secondly you're not combining the 2 comparisons correctly: the result of the comparison will be -1,0,or 1. These are all truthy values and `true && foo` is just `foo`, so your code would just sort by the y values

You could write this as

```
x_ordering = a.x <=> b.x
x_ordering == 0 ? a.y <=> b.y : x_ordering
```

However array already implements `<=>` so you could just do

```
array.sort! { |a,b| [a.x, a.y] <=> [b.x, b.y]}
```

Which is a little terser and clearer at expense of creating 2  arrays in each comparison

You could even do

```
 array.sort_by! { |a| [a.x, a.y] }
```

Which is even clearer, but with a slightly different memory profile. This creates an array with the original values replaced by the values returned by the block and uses that to sort the original array.

I'd usually use the latter version unless I had a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: oh wow, I was wondering why <==> was giving syntax errors -_-. thanks for the demo

Answer (score 4):

[Frederick Cheung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557623/477037) already describes how to sort by custom attributes.

Another option is to provide a default sort order by implementing `Coordinate#<=>`:

```
class Coordinate
  # ...

  def to_a
    [x, y]
  end

  def <=>(other)
    return unless other.is_a? Coordinate

    to_a <=> other.to_a
  end
end
```

And just call:

```
coordinate_array.sort!
```

You can also include the [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Comparable.html) mixin which ...

> (...) uses `<=>` to implement the conventional comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, and `>`) and the method `between?`.

Comment: Upvote for the reference to `Comparable` (even if you hadn't mentioned `between?`).

Answer (score 1):

Stefan already described how to implement the `<=>()` method for your class.  Here's another way:

```
class Coordinate
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def to_s
    "(#{x}, #{y})"
  end

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def <=>(other)
    [x, y] <=> [other.x, other.y]
  end
end


arr = [
  Coordinate.new(1, 2),
  Coordinate.new(0, 3),
  Coordinate.new(0, 2),
]

puts arr
puts "-" * 10
puts arr.sort!

--output:--
(1, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 2)
----------
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 2)
```

See the [Array docs](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for how `[1, 1] <=> [1, 0]` works.